# Prisma adapter Next-auth NextJS

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

I have upgraded to the latest version of the prisma adapter. when i login using the google provider the prisma adapter get everything right in the database however the callback takes me to login page instead of redirecting to the home page. if i remove the prisma adapter the app behaves correctly

i am using:

packages

- @next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.7
- @prisma/client": "^5.2.0
- next-auth": "^4.23.1

middleware

```
export { default } from 'next-auth/middleware';
```

options

```
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GitHubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github';
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
    debug: true,
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string
        }),
        GitHubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string
        }),
     ],
}
```

on debug i have no errors, however no redirection to the home page i cannot understand exactly where the issue lies.

Comment: Is your repository open source?
If yes, could you share it?

Comment: https://github.com/a-nasseur/booksSummary.git here is the repository i put it on public. if you uncomment the prisma adapter you could not use the login function anymore